# Outbound Calling

Tags: asterisk, trixbox, outboundrules

I can't seem to get outbound calling for Asterisk working.

**::Useful Info::**
trixbox Version: 2.8.0.4
Asterisk Version: 1.6
Pastebins: http://pastebin.com/6eH87Nri | http://pastebin.com/MU6F6dDC

The calls are supposed to transit a trunk provided by IP Communications. The trunk is configured but outbound does not work. Internal and inbound calling both work.

If other people have this working, it would be greatly appreciated if you would explain how you did so. I have googleing my fingers off for the past week and can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: This is not useful information. What is the destination you want to reach? VoIP, ISDN, analog? What goes wrong? Can you reach internal extensions?

Comment: @mailq. Please check above. I have updated it with the information you requested.

Comment: Can you pastebin some of your existing config dialplan, and some associated conf files?

Comment: Screenshot: http://grab.by/cEK4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really bought a trunk at "IP Communications", then according to [this](http://www.ipcomms.net/product-asterisk.html) you get free support for Asterisk from them.

And you can see an installation and configuration Howto for Trixbox [here](http://www.ipcomms.net/product-trixbox.html)

But in either case: When you want help from us then we need more information than "it does not work".

Comment: If if make a call it will drop but just before it will say "Service Unreachable" and then

Comment: What is in the logs while you call out?

Comment: Updates above...

Comment: WTF! Are you intentionally fooling us? Your first pastbin shows all lines commented out and the second one is invalid. No logs readable!

Comment: What are you talking about? Ok I don't know what happened to the second one. Did you not look at the grabby. What log's do you want? I thought the output from the Asterisk console would suffice... but I though wrong.